# Pull 1 column from Teradata LDAP and store in array/table to use in script

Tags: powershell, active-directory, teradata

My PowerShell skills are weak/rusty.  Seeking a little help.

Overall, I want to do the following:

1. Pull a static list of Active Directory group names from Teradata using LDAP.

   ```
   SELECT GroupName FROM DB1.AdGroupList
   ```
2. Store those entries in a table in memory to reference.
3. Use `Get-ADGroupMember` to get members of each of those groups.
4. Put that group name and AD data into a 2nd Teradata table.

   ```
   "Insert into DB1.AdGroupMembers
   (GroupName, Name, GivenName, SurName, SamAccountName)"
   ```

The first problem is getting the Teradata data from LDAP and storing it.
There is very little PowerShell help for Teradata.

Answer (score 0):

A teammate derived a simplier but functional solution.  The AD list is hardcoded in the script and the output is to a text file.  SSIS will pickup the text file.  This is not the full solution, but enabled us to stop running a MS Access process.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$ObjectResults = @()
$Groups =  "HardCodedGroup1","HardCodedGroup1"
Foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
$Members = (Get-ADGroupMember $Group)
# $Uname = ( Get-ADUser -Filter $Group | Select-Object  samaccountname )

ForEach ($Member in $Members)
{
    $Out = New-Object PSObject
    $Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Name -Value $Member.Name
    $Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Group -Value $Group
    $Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name USERNAME -Value 
$Member.samaccountname

    $Out

    $ObjectResults += $Out
}

}

$ObjectResults | export-csv C:\Temp\AD\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```